# BSOD on Windows 7 install - Linux works fine

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, bsod, windows-installation

I'm trying to install Windows 7 64-bit on my machine:

- Intel Core 2 Duo E4500
- 3GB RAM (although only 2884608K reported in BIOS)
- GeForce 210 1GB
- Abit IB9 motherboard

memtest86+ reports no errors in memory.

It results in BSOD with DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL error.

I find it strange, because Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit works fine here.

I suspect this is graphics drivers' fault, because I had previously Windows XP (or Vista) installed and it stopped working showing BSOD with an error in nVidia driver, just as I updated to GeForce 210.

Because Ubuntu works (games, flash, movies included), I suspect the hardware is fine and I just need to get the correct drivers to load before installation.

Is my thinking correct? How can I install Windows 7 here?

Comment: More information about when the BSOD happens.  This a fresh install or an existing one, far to many questions, left unanswered.

Comment: It's a fresh install (I prepared free partition). After the system boots, there is progress bar at the bottom (Windows loading). Then there is some animated graphic with "Starting" at the bottom, for a few seconds - and here it happens. If there's any info omitted, please ask.

Comment: Try disconnecting all unnecessary USB/other devices before install, and see if that works.

Comment: I tried that, even without mouse and keyboard connected, disabled things like IDE controller in BIOS (isn't required for SATA) - still no success :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has this problem, it was solved by disabling EIST (Enhanced Intel SpeedStep Technology) in BIOS

as described on http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprohardware/thread/4005e470-534a-4b00-83b8-c4a305da0e50